# Libgdx -- scene2d actors scaling

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm working on an android project in LibGDX which I mainly test using the DesktopLauncher. I have some UI, set using Scene2d elements. They look great on Desktop, but really off using an emulated nexus 7. How can I make them scale correctly and have the same position as on Desktop?

Thing is, I've set a button , for example, to have position x=300, y=200. While this looks good on Desktop, it differs on mobile. How can I scale them in such a way that the positions are the same, no matter the resolution?

I've found online about viewports, but they didn't help.

Comment: show your code, what you've done yet ?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find an answer. For all those who might have this issue in the future, I solved the problem using this guide

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

On top of that, what fixed my issue was setting

```
viewport.apply(true);
```

The parameter centers the camera, that solved my issue.